# Query attempt using Node.js dynamoDB document client is not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to write a lambda function that retrieves data from a dynamodb table which is called `simul-MOCK_LEADS_TBL`. I have come up with the following nodejs code to achieve this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-2'}); 

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
var table = "simul-MOCK_LEADS_TBL";
var lead_email = "hwdnpny@xyz.com";
  var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "lead_email": lead_email
    }
};
  docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) { 
      callback(err, null);
    } else { 
      callback(null, data.Items); 
    }
  });
}
```

The ultimate goal is to basically query the table based on the email which will passed in the event key. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
  "errorType": "ValidationException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
    "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
  ]
}

Request ID:
"7d76c52a-3c61-11e8-b415-093987d0d3bc"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 7d76c52a-3c61-11e8-b415-093987d0d3bc Version: $LATEST
2018-04-10T01:50:05.834Z    7d76c52a-3c61-11e8-b415-093987d0d3bc    {"errorMessage":"The provided key element does not match the schema","errorType":"ValidationException","stackTrace":["Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)","Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)","Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)","Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)","Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)","AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)","/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10","Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)","Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)","Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"]}
END RequestId: 7d76c52a-3c61-11e8-b415-093987d0d3bc
REPORT RequestId: 7d76c52a-3c61-11e8-b415-093987d0d3bc  Duration: 215.36 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB
```

I have checked multiple documentation and web sites and they are all following the same code to do this, however I am not sure why it is not working for me:

**Resources**:

https://rishabh.io/misc/dynamodb-with-nodejs.html
https://medium.com/quick-code/node-js-restful-api-with-dynamodb-local-7e342a934a24

**Note: --- TABLE DETAILS ----**

```
Table name  simul-MOCK_LEADS_TBL
Primary partition key   lead_email (String)
Primary sort key    lead_id (String)
Point-in-time recovery  DISABLEDEnable
Encryption  DISABLED
Time to live attribute  DISABLEDManage TTL
Table status    Active
Creation date   April 6, 2018 at 12:19:00 PM UTC-7
UTC: April 6, 2018 at 7:19:00 PM UTC

Local: April 6, 2018 at 12:19:00 PM UTC-7

Region (Oregon): April 6, 2018 at 11:19:00 AM UTC-8

Provisioned read capacity units 5 (Auto Scaling Enabled)
Provisioned write capacity units    5 (Auto Scaling Enabled)
Last decrease time  -
Last increase time  -
Storage size (in bytes) 34.22 KB
Item count  107
Region  US West (Oregon)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table has a primary sort key. So for GetItem function, you need to pass both `partition key` and `sort key` in the parameter.

```
var params = {
TableName: table,
Key:{
    "lead_email": lead_email,
    "lead_id": some_lead_id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try that and it is returning null even though there is an entry for that composite primary key. Anyways solved it by using query on the following parameter:                                                
    var params = {
            TableName: table,
            KeyConditionExpression: "#lead_email = :lead_email",
            ExpressionAttributeNames:{
                "#lead_email": "lead_email"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":lead_email": lead_email
            }
        };